# Incorrect generated SQL-Statement using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Before I describe my exact problem, I'm going to show you the relevant code. I have a Database consisting of two entities (**PaymentProvider** and **Country**) and a join-table to implement a Many-To-Many relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE paymentprovider (
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    displayName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(name)
);

CREATE TABLE country (
    code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(code)
);

CREATE TABLE providercountry (
    paymentprovider_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    country_code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(paymentprovider_name) REFERENCES paymentprovider(name),
    FOREIGN KEY(country_code) REFERENCES country(code)
);
```

The Java-Implementation looks like this (Using JPA):

**Country**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Country.GET_ALL,
            query ="SELECT c FROM Country c")
})
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    private String code;
    private String name;
    private List<PaymentProvider> paymentProviders = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final String PREFIX = "foo.bar";
    public static final String GET_ALL = PREFIX + ".get_all";

    public Country(){
    }

    @Id
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity=PaymentProvider.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "providercountry", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "code")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "paymentprovider_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
    public List<PaymentProvider> getPaymentProviders() {
        return paymentProviders;
    }

    public void addPaymentProviders(PaymentProvider paymentProvider) {
        this.paymentProviders.add(paymentProvider);
    }

    public void setPaymentProviders(List<PaymentProvider> paymentProviders) {
        this.paymentProviders = paymentProviders;
    }
```

**PaymentProvider:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "paymentprovider")
public class PaymentProvider implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private String name;
    private String displayname;
    private List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();

    public PaymentProvider(){
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "paymentProviders")
    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void addCountry(Country country) {
        this.countries.add(country);
    }

    public void setCountries(List<Country> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return displayname;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.displayname = code;
    }

    @Id
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And all I'm trying to do, is to execute the SQL-Statement like this:

```
public List<Country> getAll() {
    TypedQuery<Country> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Country.GET_ALL, Country.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Which leaves me with an error:

*Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "PAYMENTPRO1_.CODE" not found;*

So I went ahead and took a look at the generated SQL:

```
select  paymentpro0_.country_code as country_1_0_0_, 
        paymentpro0_.paymentprovider_name as paymentp2_2_0_, 
        paymentpro1_.name as name1_1_1_, 
        paymentpro1_.code as code2_1_1_ 
from    providercountry paymentpro0_ inner join paymentprovider paymentpro1_ 
        on paymentpro0_.paymentprovider_name=paymentpro1_.name 
        where paymentpro0_.country_code=?
```

It seems to me, that - somehow - the Country and the PaymentProvider entites get confused, because, as the generated SQL statement shows, there is a join with the paymentprovider-table instead of the country-table. Any idea where i got something confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an eager fetch on the `PaymentProvider` relationship in `Country`. The query you posted is the eager fetch of payment provider for the country.

It is failing because you have no code column on payment provider but you have one in your `PaymentProvider` entity method. It is mapping your entity based on the method not on the private `displayName` variable.